# JQuery is not working in my Google Chrome extension, content script?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

As mentioned in chrome extension development tutorial I can include jQuery in my `manifest.json` file to use it in a content script like so:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

I did that. But when I open the javascript console and click on the browser action icon of my extension, I see the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

What should I have to do!? I can't understand what's wrong.

---

Updates from OP, originally posted as answers:

As requested, here is my complete manifest and content script sample.
manifest.json:

```
"name": "My Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_title": "My Extension"
},

"background": {"page": "background.html"},
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
"js": ["jquery-1.8.3.js","content.js"]
}],

"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
```

content script snippet:

```
var message = $('body').width();
chrome.extension.sendMessage (message);
```

---

---

Re rsanchez's answer.
I'll try to explain in detail. As is well known we can open two javascript consoles. the first is associated with extension's popup.html and the second associated with currently opened web page. I have following code snippet (for example) in content script and in script included in popup.html

```
var = bodyWidth$('body').width(); 
console.log(bodyWidth);
```

When I open console associated with currently opened web page I receive error mentioned above, but when I open js console associated with extension's popup.html I can see body's width displayed in console. that's mean script included in popup.html refers to jQuery library and content script not.

Comment: Content scripts are not the same as browser actions. Please include in your question the relevant parts that define and handle the browser action.

Comment: excuse me, parts of what? could you tell in detail, please? I have content script and script which is included in popup.html (this script is run every time I click browser action).

Comment: please see my answer below

Comment: Please include your complete manifest at least. If the fragment you included comes from your manifest, keep in mind that google usually uses https instead of http.

Comment: I think that it's because jquery sets $ on the window variable, as in window.$ not just $

Comment: “When I … click on the browser action icon…, I see the error” is different than “When I open console associated with currently opened web page I receive error”.  “we can open two javascript consoles”: there’s three you should be looking at: (1) for the current webpage (in the extension’s context) (2) for popup.html (3) for background.html.  When does your error happen?  What is that page’s html?  And please copy and paste your code.

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome doesn't support an external `jquery.js` file from/in the manifest.
You must [download jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js) and put it in the extension folder. Then you can add it to `manifest.json`.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that, but it didn't help. I receive error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" anyway.

Comment: Something you are not showing us is the problem, post or link to your *complete* manifest and *complete* `myscript.js`. Or **make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).**

Comment: Please, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery in a script included in `popup.html`, you need to include `jquery.js` in `popup.html` before your script.

Comment: Yes, I know. I can use jQuery in javascript which I included in popup.html, but I want to use jQuery in my content script too, but it doesn't work unfortunately...

Comment: You said you see the error when you click on your browser action icon. That would mean the error comes from the popup, not the content script.

Comment: Please, see my answer below

Comment: @anykey3, Do not post updates to the ***question*** as answers!  Edit the question instead.  Also, the code snippet is obviously not valid syntax.  Stop editing or hiding the code.  If it's sensitive, make a proper working example with valid syntax and **that we can run AS-IS**, to see the problem you report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer the jquery.js file as below, similar to content script js file. 
It worked for me.

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent( function(currentWindow) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id}, function(activeTabs){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      activeTabs[0].id, {file: 'jquery.min.js', allFrames: true}
    );
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      activeTabs[0].id, {file: 'select_links.js', allFrames: true}
    );
  });
  console.log(currentWindow.id);
});
```